# Why the result different everytime after I run the same query in spark?

Tags: apache-spark-mllib, collaborative-filtering

I use collaborative filtering in mllib to train an ALS model on my spark cluster. I use python api.

```
als = ALS(maxIter=10, rank=10, regParam=0.01, userCol="member_srl", itemCol="productid", ratingCol="rating")
model = als.fit(training)
pred = model.transform(test)
```

but when I check the pred, it seems it is changing.
If I run the query `pred.count()`, the result is not steady with a little variance. So why the result is always changing.

for example:

```
pred.count()
```

4219257

run it again:

```
pred.count()
```

4220723

run it again:

```
pred.count()
```

4222431

Comment: Not sure which language you are using - please add a tag

Answer (score 0):

ALS is an algorithm that is initialized with random numbers. So a little variance is to be expected. Try it with an explicit seed number, like:

```
als.setSeed(123)
```

Comment: Actually, I just produce the 'pred' only once. I have not run the first three lines of queries many times. Once the pred is produced, the count of it changes when I run pred.count().

Comment: I do not know whether pred.createOrReplaceTempView("pred") matters and influence the pred result.